# Does Contiki-NG support the Rime protocol, or is there an equivalent?

Tags: iot, contiki, contiki-ng, radio-transmission

The Contiki OS supports a series of so-called Rime protocols [ http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01798.html ] and one of these, "abc", would have been ideal for a lowish-level radio test I have been tasked with writing.

However, I am required to use contiki-ng, and on studying that I can find, to my amazement, no reference to Rime or the "abc" protocol!

Has the Rime protocol been removed from contiki-ng, and if so is there an equivalent low-level protocol for simply transmitting and receiving radio packets over a specified channel without all the higher networky layers?

If the worst comes to the worst, I suppose I can use UDP. But to stress-test the IoT device I am using I would have preferred a lower-level protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the support for Rime was removed when Contiki-NG was forked. You can use UDP. It is quite efficient due to the 6LoWPAN header compression especially if you don't need features such as IP fragmentation. Alternatively, you can use the lower-level radio API or MAC protocol API directly, for example by calling `NESTACK_MAC.send` or `NESTACK_RADIO.send`.